# Is it possible return an function with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Let's assume I need to make an ajax call to my server

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'url/url', 
    success: function(response){}
});
```

and as a response from the server I reply with some javascript code

```
res.send("const myFunc = (b) => { console.log(b) }");
```

Is there a way to do something like this?:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'url/url', 
    success: function(response){ 
        response('hello'); //I would like 'hello' to appear in the console
    }
});
```

Comment: `eval` or `new Function`

Comment: @Konrad any sources where I can read both the documentation and see some examples?

Comment: @DmytroV ... did the OP ever hear of [`MDN`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) documentations and its [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)? ... [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) where with the latter `new Function` is considered to be kind of an `eval`uation.

Comment: It's worth reading the entire MDN documentation btw, you can easily learn new things this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with [Function() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'url/url', 
    success: function(response){
        const fn = new Function('x', `${response}; myFunc(x)`)
        fn('hello')
    }
});
```

Notice that you have to run the functions inside the string hence `${response}; myFunc(x)`

Here is example of how this works:

```js
const code = 'const myFunc = (b) => { console.log(b) }'
const fn = new Function('x', `${code}; myFunc(x)`)
fn('Hello')
```

It could be easier if you would send array like that:

```
res.send("b", "console.log(b)");
```

You could then use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'url/url', 
    success: function(response){
        const fn = new Function(...response)
        fn('hello')
    }
});
```